# Automating through ZNC logs?

Tags: python

I am currently an oper for multiple irc servers, and I am trying to have a reliable way to log our channels due to a high amount of abuse. I have for the current time been using pierc, but I need all the functionality of ZNC.

My question is, using python what would be a simple way to loop through the ZNC log directory to parse the logs into a mysql database. The directory looks like the following:

username_ircnetwork_channel_20160209.log  username2_ircnetwork2_channel_20160209.log

I know I can itterate through each file with something to this effect:

```
fileOpen = open("~/.znc/moddata/log/")
fileOpen = fileOpen.read().splitlines()
for line in fileOpen:
    do something
```

However I am at a loss at a clean way to cycle through the log directory to check each file. Is there a decent way in python to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's `os` module with `listdir` and loop through the files:

```
import os

path = '/path/to/logs/'
listing = os.listdir(path)

for infile in listing:
    with open(path + infile, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        # parse however you need
```

↳ https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html